# cannot get data in php sdk facebook 5.6

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api

I try get data for php graphe sdk facebook 5.6 but I don't get for exaple user_likes

this is code php:

```
$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'app id', 
  'app_secret' => 'secret id',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11'
]);


if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $token = $request->request->get('token');
    $response= $fb->get('me?fields=id,name,email,last_name,first_name,gender,locale,users_likes,birthday',$token);
    $userNode = $response->getGraphNode();
}
```

but response is name,gender,email,lastname,firstname,locale btu birthday and user_likes I d'ont anything

Comment: My first thought, Facebook changed access to retrieve information. Users explicitly needs to give access to give information.

Comment: Did the user grant user_likes permission to your app?

Comment: @wizkid how to grant user_likes permission to my app !?

Comment: @Xorifelse how to access to give information with new change access information !?

Answer (score 0):

```
$response= $fb->get('me?fields=id,...,likes,birthday',$token);
```

You used `users_likes` - that is not even a valid permission (because that would be `user_likes`).

Comment: @luschen and how to add user_likes in valid permission !?

Comment: You read the Facebook documentation for how to ask the user for permission

Comment: you successfully asked for the email and birthday permissions already. right there.

Comment: @WizKid i add submission and i add details then send request submission to developers facebook .. this is way to add permission in my application !?

Comment: again, you did use the email and birthday permission already. so just use the user_likes permission EXACTLY where you are using the email and user_birthday permissions.

Comment: @luschn also error I use $fb->get('me?fields=id,...,likes,birthday',$token); but also error

Comment: i really hope that you did not just copy that line, including the dots ;) - also, if there is an error, ALWAYS add the error message. no one will be able to help you if you just tell us "there is an error".

Comment: My friend any message error is display but when I add birthday and likes in response i haven't any birtheday or likes

Comment: oh, i misunderstood. did you ask for the user_birthday permission too then? and what means "any message error"? do you get an error or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168117/discussion-between-sf-2018-and-luschn).

Comment: Any message error .. but any result also .. I send request for get user_birthday and likes but response is empty bo birthday and no likes .. I don't khnow where is error or I use not correctly api ... I use api 2.11 and php graph sdk 5.6

Comment: debug the access token and make sure it includes the neccessary permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/